# List object property as Key in LINQ GroupBy clause

Tags: c#, linq

Hey i want to ask if its possible to use List object property in GroupBy clausule:

MyProblem:

I want to group a list by a property directly from a list, and from object 
which this list contains

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{

class ExampleDocument
{
    public int idDoc { get; set; }
    public List<Payments> payments { get; set; }

    public string date { get; set; }

    public ExampleDocument(int a, List<Payments> paymentss,string d)
    {
        idDoc = a;
        payments = paymentss;
        d = date;
    }
}
class Payments
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }

    public Payments(int a, string b)
    {
        value = a;
        method = b;
    }
}
class Program
{
    List<ExampleDocument> exampleList = new List<ExampleDocument>();
    List<Payments> listOfPayments = new List<Payments>();
    Payments a = new Payments(1000, "cash");
    Payments b = new Payments(2000, "card");

    void Work()
    {
        listOfPayments.Add(a);
        listOfPayments.Add(b);
        exampleList.Add(new ExampleDocument(1, listOfPayments,"2018-08-06"));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program c = new Program();

        c.exampleList.GroupBy(p => new { p.date, ((Payments)p.payments).method });
    }
}
```

}

"((Payments)p.payments).method }" here i got exception

> Cannot convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'ConsoleApp8.Payments'

1. ExampleList - contains commercial documents.
2. p.Example_VARIABLE - is the date of issue of the document.
3. Payments is class which contains property of payments
4. payments is a list of all payments (in document)
5. method is a payment method

---

As Cetin Bastoz answer i managed new query

```
namespace ConsoleApp8
```

{

```
class ExampleDocument
{
    public int idDoc { get; set; }
    public int DocNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Payments> payments { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }

    public ExampleDocument(int a, int docNumber, List<Payments> paymentss, string d)
    {
        idDoc = a;
        payments = paymentss;
        DocNumber = docNumber;
        date = d;
    }
}
class Payments
{
    public int payID { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }

    public Payments(int PayID, int a, string b)
    {
        payID = PayID;
        value = a;
        method = b;
    }
}
class Program
{
    List<ExampleDocument> exampleList = new List<ExampleDocument>();
    List<Payments> listOfPayments = new List<Payments>();

    void Work()
    {
        Payments a = new Payments(2, 1000, "cash");
        Payments b = new Payments(1, 2000, "card");

        listOfPayments.Add(a);
        listOfPayments.Add(b);
        exampleList.Add(new ExampleDocument(1, 20189, listOfPayments, "2018-08-06"));
        exampleList.Add(new ExampleDocument(1, 201810, listOfPayments, "2018-08-08"));
        exampleList.Add(new ExampleDocument(1, 201811, listOfPayments, "2018-08-09"));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program c = new Program();
        c.Work();
        var data2 = from d in c.exampleList
                    from p in d.payments
                    select new
                    {
                        Number = d.DocNumber,
                        DocDate = d.date,
                        payID = p.payID,
                        Amount = p.value
                    } into s
                    group s by s.DocDate into g
                    select g;

        var sDocDate = "2018-08-06";
        var result = data2.Select(x => x.Where(p => p.DocDate.Equals(sDocDate)));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}
Everthing is clear, untill i want to compare date2 result to date given from string

```
var sDocDate = "2018-01-21"
var result = data2.Select(x => x.Where(p => p.DocDate.Equals(sDocDate)));
```

[Why at bottom image "result" got those "1,2,3 variable without entries"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifvkc.png)

Comment: Where in your code sample is there an ArrayList object? I don't see one, and you left out all class and type definitions. Also ArrayList is very oldfashioned (.NET 1) and if possible you should List<T> instead.

Comment: "((ExampleObject)x.ExampleArray).ExampleProperty" - here i got can't Convert Array to Object.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51706708/edit) and make it as clear as you can by adding the text of your comment + all that you can think of that might make it clearer (including e.g. the type declarations of `ExampleArray` and `ExampleObject`).

Comment: The fundamental issue is that `ExampleDocument` has a `payments` property which is a `List<Payments>`. You then try and cast that `List` to a **single** payment. This doesn't make sense. A carton of eggs is not a single egg.

Comment: @mjwills   I know about it, my problem is that im stuck at **GroupBy 'date' and the payment 'method', just wanna know if at that structure of code is possible to do this by GroupBy linq and get any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use OfType<>() to get ExampleObject types from an ArrayList (I thought nobody left still using ArrayList):

```
var grouped = exampleList.OfType<ExampleObject>()
   .GroupBy(p => new { p.EXAMPLE_VARIABLE, p.ExampleProperty});
```

EDIT: Although your code is faulty, after correcting it:

```
var data = from d in exampleList
           from p in d.payments
           group p by new {DocDate=d.date, PayType=p.method} into g
           select g;
```

Comment: It's close to I edited first post with fast full example.

Comment: @LitteProgrammer, what do you mean? I don't see any sample data.

Comment: I edited my question by another question Could you please look at it?